# rails 3 dynamically populating dropdowns

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 2 dropdown in a view. First drop down is automatically populated when the view get's loaded with the list of options. when an item is selected I would like to populate the dropdown # 2.

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple ways of doing this. You can either do an AJAX call (responding to the selection of a value in dropdown #1). The downside to this is that it requires a round-trip call to the server, then updating the value of dropdown #2 with the result.

The other way is to pre-load all possible values for dropdown #2 when the page first loads, and just change it in the browser with JavaScript as soon as the value is changed (rather than making a call all the way back to the server to get the values).

Either way, you're modifying the DOM, most likely, so it'll be some kind of JavaScript solution. Whether you choose AJAX, or preload and change it immediately will probably depend on how it affects the original page load speed, how much data you want to load onto the client, etc. If it's a relatively small number of options possible in dropdown #2, then pre-loading might be your best bet.

Comment: What is a great way to do this with 3 dropdowns? Question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443561/how-to-link-3-dynamic-dropdowns-select-elements-in-rails-4